# Combine two arrays and downcast elements

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays with 2 `UIView` elements each and I want to combine them into 1 array while downcasting the elements to `UIImageView`.

Is there a better way to do this than adding flapMapped arrays?

```
let topViews = [UIView(), UIView()]
let bottomViews = [UIView(), UIView()]

let imageViews = topViews.flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView } + bottomViews.flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }
```

*My use case is putting `arrangedSubviews` of 2 different stack views in one array (in case `topViews` and `bottomViews` look stupid, it's just for simplicity).

Comment: You could add the 2 arrays then `flatMap` the result, but I don't see why that'd be any different from what you have. I don't think there's a "better" way to solve your particular task.

Comment: `(topViews + botomViews).flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }`

Answer (score 1):

It's a nice solution and only slightly better way is, as @zgorawski mentioned,

```
let imageViews = (topViews + bottomViews).flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }`
```

since now if you would want to add another array to the equation, you just have to add `+ anotherOne` instead of `+ anotherOne.flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }`.

Comment: While you will get the same result, combining the arrays before iterating is better in every way I can think of. It prevents logic duplication and is MUCH more flexible. (e.g. adding an additional array requires simply adding `, otherArray` v.s. having to copy and paste the entire flatMap with the new array)

Comment: @PeejWeej in his particular case it's not really important, but you are right, if we want to be more general, then definitely we want to copy/paste less.. I updated the answer